# jQuery mobile, applying styling to dynamic content on Windows Phone (mango)

Tags: css, windows, windows-phone-7, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically adding content (using AJAX) to my pages. This is working fine, except for the styling, which is not applied automatically. The fix for this is to use `.trigger("create");` (e.g. `$('#content').html(data).trigger("create")` ).
This works on webkit, FF and IE (on PC), on Windows Phone's IE it refuses to work though. The content is displayed, but without any (jquery mobile) styling.
I tried using `.page` or use append instead of the 'html' to add content, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved my question. The `trigger("create")` worked fine, the problem was in the jQuery `$.ajax({ })` call.
As datatype I used text ( `dataType: "text",` ), while transferring HTML. I corrected the dataType to html (  `dataType: "html",` ) and now it works just fine.
It looks like the Windows Phone browser is more strict on this compared to Firefox, IE desktop and Chrome